# How to wrap a custom json:api client and make calls fluent and async (Non-ES6)

Tags: javascript, fluent, json-api

I want to create a custom client for a restful API that follows the json:api specification. So, I created this simple client with async support:

```
MyTools.Api = (function () {
    "use strict";
    //#region Private
    function ajax(url, method, data) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.responseType = 'json';
            //Open first, before setting the request headers.
            request.open(method, url, true);
            request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + window.headerToken)
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (request.status === 200) {
                        resolve(request.response);
                    } else {
                        reject(Error(request.status));
                    }
                }
            };
            request.onerror = function () {
                reject(Error("Network Error"));
            };
            request.open(method, url, true);
            request.send(data);
        });
    }

    //#endregion
    //#region Public
    return function (url, method, data) {
        url = window.apiBasePath + url;
        return ajax(url, method, data);
    };
    //#endregion
})(MyTools.Api || {});
```

I am passing the token from the back-end (.net) to a window global variable called headerToken. The same with the base path (apiBasePath).
Now, I can call this client like like this

```
CTools.Api("/dashboard/users/", "GET").then(function (result) {
console.log(result);
});
```

My goal is to create a more fluent way to consume the api.For example,I want to call something like:

```
mytools.api.dashboard.users.get().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    });
```

and

```
mytools.api.dashboard.users.get(fliteroptions).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    });
```

and if there is another module to use like

```
mytools.api.basket.items.get(fliteroptions).then(function (result) {
    onsole.log(result);
    });
```

Dashboard and basket will have different urls. Both the client and the url building will be created inside mytools namespace. Also the variables headerToken and apiBasePath will be assigned in mytools constructor after a rest call.

What design pattern to use in this case?
Keep in mind that I want a non-ES6 solution.

Comment: Is the only difference between `dashboard` and `basket` the url or what else can change? One a side note, `fetch` would seem to be simpler than `XMLHttpRequest`, no?

Comment: mytools will do all the job, set header token and also the base path. These values will be set by a rest call in the constructor of mytools. Dashboard ,basket and whatever else will only set the additional url path of the json api. In the main method (get ,update, create etc) I want also to have the options to add filter options as an input (filteroptions).

Comment: Also I am ok with fetch.Maybe it is better.I'll consider this thanks @divillysausages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's essentially only really two ways of doing what you want to do; either each route (`dashboard`, `basket`, etc) is a full api object with `fetch` behaviour etc, or the `get()` method in `dashboard` etc maps back to `api`.

Something like this:

```
class Route {
    constructor(url, api) {
        this.url = url;
        this.api = api;
    }
    
    get(filterOptions) {
        return this.api.get(this.url, filterOptions)
    }
    
    post(filterOptions) {
        return this.api.post(this.url, filterOptions);
    }
}

class Api {
    constructor(basePath) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }
    
    get(route, filterOptions) {
        // filterOptions can be null here
        return fetch(`${this.basePath}/${route}`)
            .then(data => data.json())
    }
    
    post(route, filterOptions) {
        // filterOptions can be null here
        ...
    }
    
    ...
}

mytools.api = new Api();
mytools.api.dashboard = new Route('dashboard', mytools.api);
mytools.api.basket = new Route('basket', mytools.api);
...
```

Your `Route` class is a simple class that holds a `url` and whatever else, as well as the `api` which will actually do the fetching.

`Api` wraps your `fetch` and handles any `filterOptions` passed.

When you create your `Api`, you also create all the routes.

The downside is that you need to know all of your routes beforehand.

To do it a bit more dynamically, you can look into `Proxy`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Here, you can implement a function that's called every time your object is accessed:

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name) {
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }
};
var proxy = new Proxy({}, handler);

console.log(proxy.world); // output: Hello, world
```

You should be able to hook into it so that `get` method returns the `Api` object, and you can then call directly on it

**Edit for ES5**

It's been a while since I've written pure ES5, but converting the `Route` class, for example, should look something like this:

```
function Route(url, api) {
    this.url = url;
    this.api = api;
}

Route.prototype.get = function(filterOptions) {
    return this.api.get(this.url, filterOptions)
}

Route.prototype.post = function(filterOptions) {
    return this.api.post(this.url, filterOptions)
}
```

Creating the objects should stay the same - `new Route(url, api)`

I'm not sure if `fetch` is ES5 - you'd need to look at where the code will be running to see if it's supported or not. Ditto with promises; you'd either need to use a library like `Bluebird`, or work with callbacks.

More info on classes here: https://medium.com/@apalshah/javascript-class-difference-between-es5-and-es6-classes-a37b6c90c7f8

**Edit for dynamic URLs**

If I've understood you correctly, you're getting the URLs from a REST call.

Assume that the return of this call is something like:

```
{
    "dashboard": {
        "url": "dashboard/",
        "token": "..."
    },
    "basket": {
        "url": "basket/",
        "token": "..."
    },
    ...
}
```

At this point, you can now go through and create your api:

```
mytools.api = new Api();
mytools.api.dashboard = new Route(jsonObj.dashboard.url, mytools.api);
mytools.api.basket = new Route(jsonObj.basket.url, mytools.api);
...
```

You can also pass in `token`, or whatever else is in your REST JSON object. It does mean a few things though:

1. You can't access `mytools.api.dashboard` etc until that initial REST call is made - it won't point to anything
2. You need to know your routes beforehand - e.g. here, we know that we have a route behind the `mytools.api.dashboard` variable

In relation to point 2, you can't really have truly dynamique urls (i.e. you can add `"profile"` to the REST JSON without needing to add a corresponding `mytools.api.profile` call in your codebase) without rethinking how you approach things. What you're doing here (making the API easier to work with) is pre-compile - as in, when you're writing your code. However, your routes aren't known until runtime

Comment: First of all, really thank you for your time! My mistake is that I didn't mention that I'd like an ES5 solution. It's not my choice but a prerequisite. So would be easy for you to suggest a non-ES6 solution like this one? This is the idea exactly. You caught it.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas I'm not sure I understand. Are you running your code in an environment that doesn't support classes etc, or is it just a style issue? You're not using a transpiler, is that correct? A class is essentially a glorified object though, so it should be relatively straightforward to convert - I'll add an edit

Comment: To be clear; I'm more trying to show *how* I'd approach it, rather than the specific code necessary; that would depend on your codebase

Comment: Yes @divillysausages exactly I am not allowed to use ES6 nor babel for transpiler in my case.If it could be a solution with prototypes or something equal it would be perfect.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand the approach but I can't technically implement this .For example I can't do this mytools.api I want to have a constructor with async (promises style) functionality.Think about a rest call to get a token.So for mytools.api.dashboard.get(..) dashboard will add something to url and the get will be the async func that wraps the fetch api.

Comment: For example I found that https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/fa62af0a2c57f5ef54226cae2258b38d. How can I have in ES5 an async constructor var myCircle = new Circle('mycircleid', 100, 200, 50);Not to take values as input but from a rest call.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas I've added another edit for what I think you're trying to do. Let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: Ok @divillysausages  I caught it.Thanks for all.